# appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven to generate rpc instead of rest discovery

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I have been trying to get the appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven + appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-ios demo to work using cloud endpoint.

The iOS service generator requires an rpc discovery document but mvn appengine:endpoints_get_client_lib command only generates a REST discovery document. The mvn clean install ran correctly.

How do I generate an rpc discovery client library so that the iOS service generator can accept it? More specifically, this command ->

/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ServiceGenerator-/Build/Products/Debug/ServiceGenerator \ ~/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven/target/helloendpoints-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/helloworld-v1-rpc.discovery \ --outputDir ./API

only takes a rpc.discovery while the mvn appengine:endpoints_get_client_lib only generates a rest.discovery.

Thanks,
Mochi

Comment: Still looking into this but a temporary workaround is to generate the rpc discovery doc manually using the AppEngine Java SDK script: `endpoints.sh gen-discovery-doc -o target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/ -f rpc target/generated-sources/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/helloworld-v1.api`

Comment: if you find the correct maven goal or so, please let us know as I am facing the same problem

Comment: Sorry I just noticed your post Pega88. Changing the pom.xml file appengine plugin version to 1.8.3 worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I generate an rpc discovery client library so that the iOS service generator can accept it?

`mvn appengine:endpoints_get_discovery_doc`

Comment: You should explain your answer.