# Generated discovery file for iOS endpoints fails

Tags: ios, google-app-engine

I'm hoping some one can help me out here, maybe give me an idea of what to look for. 
When I run the service generator on my discovery file I get the following output:

> Generation Settings:
>   Output Directory: ~/Desktop/endpoints
>
> Discovery RPC URL: https://www.googleapis.com/rpc?prettyPrint=false
>   Api Log Dir: ~/Desktop/endpoints
>   Flags:
>
> - Use service name directory: NO
> - Remove unknown files: NO
> - Add 'Generated' directory: NO
> - Allow rootURL overrides: YES
>     Loading API File(s):
> - Fetching ~/Desktop/myendpoint-v1-rest.discovery
>     ERROR: The api description doesn't appear to be a discovery rpc
>     description
>     Generating: 
>     Writing:
> - No changes from what is already on disk.

I tried running it both with the verbose flag and by giving it a directory to write logs in and neither gives me anymore information. I generated the endpoint using eclipse and the API works in the API explorer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ServiceGenerator needs a discovery file in **rpc** format instead of **rest** format.
You can specify the format with the argument **-f rpc**

An example:

{your_path_to_appengine_sdk}/endpoints.sh get-discovery-doc -f rpc your.package.yourAPIclass

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I failed to notice that eclipse generated rest instead of rpc discovery files. You can find a work around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013734/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven-to-generate-rpc-instead-of-rest-di). Thanks @PaulR

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't apply to most people, but if you are using Android Studio and use gradle on the backend module, the discovery docs can be automatically generated by setting `getClientLibsOnBuild = true` in the module's gradle file:

```
appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

The discovery docs are located in `<project>/<module>/build/discovery-docs/`. If they aren't generated, try deploying to App Engine, that did it for me.