# Using Google's ServiceGenerator to build the YouTube v3 API wrapper

Tags: ios, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I'm trying to build Google's generated classes for interacting with the YouTube v3 Data API. I downloaded their toolkit here:

```
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/
```

I build "ServiceGenerator" but I can't figure out exactly what I'm supposed to pass into it. This clearly doesn't work. The documentation with the tool is minimal while Google's documentation overall is rather immense so I'm having trouble tracking this down.

```
my-computer% ./ServiceGenerator https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest  --outputDir generatedYouTubeAPI --verbose
===============================================================================
Generation Settings:
  Output Directory: /svn/google-api-objectivec-client-read-only/generatedYouTubeAPI
  Discovery RPC URL: https://www.googleapis.com/rpc?prettyPrint=false
  Flags:
   + Use service name directory: NO
   + Remove unknown files: NO
   + Add 'Generated' directory: NO
   + Allow rootURL overrides: YES
Loading API URLs(s):
 + Fetching https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest
ERROR: The api description doesn't appear to be a discovery rpc description
Generating:
Writing:
 - No changes from what is already on disk.
```

Comment: This looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19122407/449161 Looking into it...

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/ would have all the sources you'd need. You don't need to generate it yourself.

Happy to help if there is an ungenerated lib.

Comment: It did in fact. Still curious how to generate though so that I understand it a little better.

Comment: did you find any success in understanding how this service generator works?